# How does the windows API method `URLDownloadToFile` handle not properly escaped URL's?

Tags: windows

How does the windows API method `URLDownloadToFile` handle not properly escaped URL's?

### Example

Image you have an URL which contains a space, this space must be percent encoded, for example `http://127.0.0.1/%20abc`. Now imagine the escape encoding would be omitted: `http://127.0.0.1/ abc`. If this url would be passed to `URLDownloadToFile`, how would `URLDownloadToFile` react?

### Possible outcomes

- `URLDownloadToFile` corrects the URL before issuing the http request, the space is replaced by `%20`.
- `URLDownloadToFile` detects the URL as invalid, does not issue an http requests and returns an error code
- `URLDownloadToFile` does not check the URL and issues an invalid http request

How does the windows API method `URLDownloadToFile` handle not properly escaped URL's?

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't documented, you must not rely on the behavior.  But the documentation does say:

> If the URL is invalid, `INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE` is returned.